# Show the definite integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(t)}{\cos(t) + i \sin(t)}\;dt$ equals $\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Wolframalpha says the integral is $\pi$.  But I can not figure out why.

`integrate (cos(x))/(cos(x) + i * sin(x)) dx from x=0 to 2pi`

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(t)}{\cos(t) + i \sin(t)}\;dt =\pi$

Might be related:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t) + i \sin(t)}\;dt =-i\pi$

Edit: Adding some context.

Let $C$ be the unit circle.

$$ \int_{C}\frac{1}{z}\;dz = 2 \pi i $$

With $ z = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{C}\frac{1}{z}\;dz 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{-\sin(t) + i\cos(t)}{\cos(t) + i \sin(t)}\;dt \\
&= -\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t) + i \sin(t)}\;dt + i\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(t)}{\cos(t) + i \sin(t)}\;dt
\end{align*}
$$

I thought might be fun to see the value of these two integrals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the integrand top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator

$I = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{ \cos(t)}{\cos(t) + i \sin(t) } dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(t) (\cos(t) - i \sin(t) ) dt $

Can you take it from here ?